# Move tag synonyms to make it more visible

Tags: feature-request, tag-synonyms

If you go to the [tags page](https://stackoverflow.com/tags), the link to the tab synonyms is located at the bottom of the page - I forgot it was there and it took me a while to find it the next time I needed it.

[image]

Would it be possible to move it up to the top along with the other tabs?

[image]

Thanks!

Comment: Agree. I cannot find tag synonym voting page even though people have been talking about it. I just know that it's there when you point it out.

Comment: Yes please. AFAICT voting for synonyms is quite useless, most sites just do the voting on a single meta post and then moderators implement the synonyms. Not sure about all sites, but many sites have this