# Tag Synonyms Approval Process

Tags: discussion, tag-synonyms

What can be done to make the tag synonyms approval process more visible?

If you go to the [tag synonym](https://stackoverflow.com/tags/synonyms?filter=suggested&tab=newest) page you'll notice that a synonym proposal by Nick Carver from Nov 2010 still doesn't have any votes (well, I just voted).

I [posted a suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/135274/move-tag-synonyms-to-make-it-more-visible) about making that page more visible hoping that will get more traffic, but that may not be enough.

I do like [Alex Lockwood's suggestion](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/137922/vote-for-tag-synonyms-directly-on-the-page) about adding the voting directly on the tag page, but still may not be enough.

Comment: One *huge* limitation is that you can only vote for tags where you have already posted. For example, I can easily see that making "ajaxpro" and "ajax-pro" synonyms would be sensible, but I cannot vote for that because I haven't posted anything about Ajax. After a couple of attempts like that, you just give up.

Comment: It practically takes a moderator on EE.SE to do any real work with the tags with the way things are set up. With no notification to users that a tag synonym suggestion exists, there is no way to draw users to vote on them.

Answer (score 2):

Maybe there could be a new badge introduced for voting on synonyms to make the process move more quickly? It seems really slow but I think it's worthwhile to match synonyms.